# Appropriate False return statement?

Tags: python, leaflet, web-mapping, folium

[image]I wanted the following Code to show green icons when the value is < 6.0 and nothing shown when it is >= 6.0 But it is returning Red icons for values >= 6.0 as in screenshot attached. What should be the Else statement for this?

```
import folium
import pandas

data=pandas.read_csv("EQ_CSV.TXT")
lat = list(data["LAT"])
lon = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["MAG"])

fga = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Magnitude below 6.0")
def color_producer(xyz):
    if xyz < 6.0:
        return 'green'
    else:
        return False

map = folium.Map(location=[24.01, 92.01], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")

for lt, ln, el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    fga.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[lt, ln], popup= "Magnitude of "+str(el),
    icon=folium.Icon(color=color_producer(el))))
```

Comment: Perhaps `xyz` is not being read as a float when the function is being executed? Try replacing `color=color_producer(el)` with `color=color_producer(float(el))` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work for me. However if I put   
 `else:
        return 'blue'` 
then it is showing blue icon for the values above 6.0. But all I wanted to was to return none when the condition is not true.

Comment: What about just removing the `else` statement entirely?

Comment: Then also showing Red icons.

Comment: Perhaps you can set the opacity to make it transparent?

Comment: Why not just filter those values out completely after creating the dataframe (e.g. data = data[data['MAG'] < 6.0])? This way you could just set a default color and wouldn't need to worry about checking the value.

Comment: That was great help, it worked. Thanks @neighdough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comment by neighdough worked for me. I had to filter out the dataset using the statement `data = data[data['MAG'] < 6.0]` and everytime I wanted another filtering e.g.  `if Magnitude > 7.0: return 'red'` then, I had to read the text file again and then use the same type filtering statement again. Like,

```
data=pandas.read_csv("EQ_CSV.TXT")
data = data[data['MAG'] > 7.0]
```